# How to generate hashmap or hashtable from list of class object using stream map in java8?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

```
class Student {
    int studentId;
    String studentName;
    String studentDept;
    public Student() {}
}
```

I have these student object list that is,

```
List<Student> studentList;
```

I want to generate hash map from these student list object.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> studentHash;
```

hashmap contain sudentid and name list key value pair.

Comment: what should be the map key and value?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service. Here's a hint: Look at the `toMap` method in `Collectors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you obviously need a **specific implementation** of `Map`, you should use the method [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) allowing to provide the `mapSupplier` instead of `toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)` because even if behind the scene it will still return an `HashMap`, it is not specified explicitly into the javadoc so you have no way to be sure that it will still be true in the next versions of Java.

So your code should be something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> studentHash = studentList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        s -> s.studentId, s -> s.studentName,
        (u, v) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                String.format("Cannot have 2 values (%s, %s) for the same key", u, v)
            );
        }, HashMap::new
    )
);
```

If you don't care about the implementation of the `Map`, simply use `toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)` as collector as next:

```
Map<Integer,String> studentHash = studentList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(s -> s.studentId, s -> s.studentName)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
studentList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Student::getStudentId, Student::getStudentName)
)
```